# Getting error Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

Tags: python-3.x

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'
app.run()

@app.route("/harry")
def harry():
    return 'Hello harry World4!'
app.run(debug=True)
```

When I am running http://127.0.0.1:5000/harry

Answer (score 1):

You added `app.run()` twice. Remove the first one, and it will work.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route("/harry")
def harry():
    return 'Hello harry World4!'
app.run(debug=True)
```